# Static Library Avoiding Symbol Collision with Wrapper

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries

I’m having a problem with 2 static libraries in C having the same symbol naming. I have access to source code, but there are over 100 files with same symbol naming, and changing the source is not really an option. I’m using gcc compiler.

I’ve tried using objcopy —-prefix-symbols, but the issue is that it adds prefixes to standard libraries like memcopy. Adding objcopy —-prefix-symbols to standard libraries is becoming excessive.

I saw other suggestions of creating a wrapper library that protects the same named symbols. The issue I have is that when I try linking with only the wrapper libraries, I’m still getting linking errors looking for the same named symbol libraries. Is it even possible to use a wrapper library to protect the same named symbols?

Comment: So, *why* do you have this situation?  Are the two or more libraries involved just naively written, in that they use poorly chosen external identifiers?  Or are they maybe intended to be alternatives to each other, such that using them together in the same program is just not supported?

Comment: Also, note that symbol renaming over large numbers of source files is totally doable with the help of an IDE that offers refactoring support.  I'm pretty sure Eclipse can do this, for example, and I don't think it's alone.  It would probably take longer to install the IDE and set up the project in it than to perform the actual refactoring.

Comment: I have this situation because the software is intended to be run on a different cpu but I’m trying to make a program to run them on the same cpu.

Comment: Using the IDE for refactoring is an interesting idea as well. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the different CPU vs same CPU distinction you're trying to make.  Do you mean that the two libraries are not designed to be used in the same *program*?  We already knew that.  The question I posed is whether that was an intentional design decision.

Comment: `but the issue is that it adds prefixes to standard libraries like memcopy` I do not understand this. So add the prefix only to the conflicting symbols.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It was an intentional design decision. They were not designed to be used in the same program.

Comment: @KamilCuk the libraries are in development and each have over 300 symbols. Of the 300 symbols, 100 are conflicted. It’s not scalable to apply to only specific symbols because it would require constant maintenance as these libraries are in development.

Comment: I asked if static wrapper libraries was even possible. Not sure if it is

Comment: Since you have access to the source, you could potentially create macros by which to rename the relevant identifiers.  That might provide for making the wanted changes in one place instead of across many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw other suggestions of creating a wrapper library that protects the same named symbols. The issue I have is that when I try linking with only the wrapper libraries, I’m still getting linking errors looking for the same named symbol libraries. Is it even possible to use a wrapper library to protect the same named symbols?

A *static* wrapper library will not serve your purpose.  Either such a library must incorporate the wrapped external objects (and therefore provide their identifiers as external symbols, too), or it must depend on those objects.  Either way, the symbols you are hoping to hide must still be included in the link when you use such a library.

For a wrapper library to do what you are looking for, it must be a dynamically-linked shared library, incorporating the wrapped objects and built with a certain amount of extra attention to which symbols it exports.

Comment: I decided not to go with a wrapper but did change the static libraries to dynamically-linked library like you suggested. The DLLs are loaded at run-time and everything is working perfectly. Thank you for the help.